# Place a 'Show/Hide' Button on a Powershell generated HTML report

Tags: html, powershell

So I'm compiling a gigantic HTML report from a bunch of PowerCLI commands. I want to make the thing a lot cleaner to scroll through because there can be lots of data just from one command. I've just started implementing HTML in my PS scripts but can't figure out a way to properly implement a 'show/hide' button of sorts. The tables are generated from the commands output being piped to ConvertTo-HTML without any html code from me so I was thinking of making the table caption clickable to show/hide the table. I've tried looking through the web but the javascript examples I find use table id's which I can't set, to my knowledge, since I don't actually construct the tables.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what the html produced by Powershell looks like (some example code perhaps), but using ID's is actually not required, though it is common practice (cause it is easy and performant).

A few lines of jQuery would accomplish what you want:

```
// initial hide of the table contents
$('table tbody').hide();

// click handler for the table header
$('table thead').click(function() {
    // get the tbody, that goes with the clicked header, and toggle visisbility
    $(this).siblings('tbody').toggle();
});
```

An example can be found here:
http://jsfiddle.net/tJg97/

How to get that (and the jQuery library) loaded in your html I leave up to you. As I am a Mac user, I don't use Powershell, so I can't help you there...

Answer (score 0):

You can add an ID, or whatever, tag to you table elements using [calculated tables](http://powershell.org/wp/2013/04/29/name-that-property/) but you'd have to [fix the HTML output](http://www.powershellmagazine.com/2013/03/25/pstip-fixing-the-output-of-convertto-html/?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+PowershellMagazine+%28PowerShell+Magazine%29).

```
$helpTbl = Get-Command -CommandType Cmdlet |
Where-Object {$_.HelpUri} |
Select Name,@{n='HelpUri';e={"<a href=`"$($_.HelpUri)`" ID=`"6`">$($_.HelpUri)</a>"}} -First 3 |
ConvertTo-Html
```

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what the code above is doing. I tried running it separately in the PS console but couldnt get it to do anything.

Comment: Sorry bad quoting, fixed it. The sample code is a way to add ID tags to the HTML that PowerShell outputs. But like I say in the answer, you need to fix the HTML output. Otherwise  it will look like this `<td>&lt;a href=&quot;http://go.microsoft.com&quot; ID=&quot;6&quot;&gt;` When it should look like `<td><a href="http://go.microsoft.com" ID="6">`